# What is the dereference operator of a type in Go generics?

Tags: go, pointers, generics

When doing generics, one can create a pointer type from any type, see [Pointer Method Example section in Types Parameter Proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#Pointer-method-example). Example:

```
type Pointer[T any] interface {
    *T // non-interface type constraint element
    // ... more constraints ...
}
```

How does one do the opposite, declare a dereference of a type ? Something like:

```
type Deref[T any] interface {
   ???T  // If T=="*int", this would refer to "int"
   ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you can explain what "dereference of a type" means in "non-generic" Go somebody might be able to help you. Actually you cannot.

Comment: If `T==int`, what would `???T` refer to?

Comment: Per comments below: this operator would only work for underlying pointer types, and yield a compilation error otherwise. So if "???" would be that operator:

???*int  -> int ;
???int -> compilation error ;
???***int -> **int ;
???**int -> *int ;

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "dereference of a type".

Pointer types are *composite types*, i.e. you need a base type to begin with. You can't go the other way around.

**What to do instead**

If you want to force non-pointer types in a constraint, specify the non-pointer types:

```
// will disallow *int
type NonPointerInt interface {
    ~int
}
```

**Notes**

- the above is not generalizable to any `T`. Using `~T` in a type set where `T` is a type parameter is [explicitly disallowed](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#arbitrary-type-constraint-element): *"Using ~T is not permitted if T is a type parameter or if T is an interface type"*.
- you may add more related types to the union, e.g. `~int | ~int32 | ~int64`
  etc. With this you're getting closer to [`constraints.Signed`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/constraints/constraints.go#L12) or similar constraints offered by the standard lib
- you may add more (partially) unrelated types, e.g. `~int | ​~string` but then you're reducing the operations you can do on values with such constraint.

---

About the letter of your question, a pointer type `*T` is useful to achieve (arbitrary levels of) indirection from a base type, and it has a precise practical meaning, tied to the concept of a pointer as the address of a memory location. It's unclear what a hypothetical "dereference type" would be in practical terms, without using a circular definition.

Comment: I think @icza above mentioned also that a "dereference of type" operator wouldn't be applicable to something that is not a pointer. But I don't see the issue with that: since types are known at compile time, they can just generate an error.

My point is: *if the base type is a pointer*, you can go the other way round.

Comment: @Jan I know what you're saying. The thing is, a pointer has a precise meaning, it's the address of a memory location. And a pointer type `*T` is a means of saying "this is the address of (a memory location of) a value of type `T`".  Let's pretend you could write `#T` as a hypothetical dereference-type, what would *that* mean?

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your question, because the answer seem obvious (pls let me know if you meant something different). But let me try: If you have: `type IntP *int` and `type MyInt #IntP`, then `MyInt` would be an alias for `int`.

Comment: Your definition is circular; you're defining `#S` in terms of itself. However it's hard to conduct further discussion on this topic in these small comments. I'd recommend to either come to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240667/go), or open an issue in the Go [issue tracker](https://github.com/golang/go/issues), to get more input from the language contributors

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is circular for the contrived example. My original point is that in a generics definition, the original type (`int`) in this case, may not be known. It could be something like `type [T any] Deref2Stringer{ String() string ;  ##T }`

Answer (score 2):

You can only dereference pointer *vaues*, but not types. `*T` is not dereferencing the `T` type, `*T` is a [type literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Types), composing a [pointer type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Pointer_types) whose base type will be `T`.

The compiler only allows operations on values of type parameters that are allowed on the constrained types.

Using `any`, all types will be allowed, even non-pointer types, whose values cannot be dereferenced.

To dereference a value, it must be a pointer. One way is to specify a parameter to be of type `*T` like in this example:

```
func deref[T any](p *T) T {
    return *p
}
```

`T` can be of any type, but `*T` will surely be a pointer type, whose values *can* be dereferenced. Testing it:

```
p := &image.Point{1, 2}
x := deref(p)
log.Printf("%T %v\n", x, x)

p := new(int)
*p = 3
x := deref(p)
log.Printf("%T %v\n", x, x)
```

Output will be:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 image.Point (1,2)
2009/11/10 23:00:00 int 3
```

Another option is to use a constraint that allows only pointer types, for example only `*int`:

```
func deref2[T interface{ *int }](p T) {
    log.Printf("%T %v\n", *p, *p)
}
```

Testing it:

```
p := new(int)
*p = 4
deref2(p)
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 int 4
```

Although using generics here has no use, you could just substitute `T` with `*int`, without type parameters.

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Jjxa1g3jPHr?v=gotip).

Comment: Thanks @icza. 

I found that odd that in types we are only allowed to create pointer of other types, but not a de-reference of them. So I was wondering.

I understand with some crafting of the type parameters, one can re-write generic functions/types using the de-referenced base type, and derive the pointed types (instead of deriving the dereferenced type). But that may require the user of the generic function to know the dereferenced type.

Comment: I mean, before generics there would be no need for a type literal that refers to a dereferenced type of a pointer type T.

Comment: @Jan I don't think it's odd. Think about it: you can create a pointer type of any type (e.g. `*int`, `*inteface{}` etc.), but you can't dereference values of any type, only pointer types. One direction is always allowed, the other is not.

Comment: @icza "One direction is always allowed, the other is not" --- only because there is no "pointer" generic constraints. I think that would be the core of the question.

Comment: Yes,  I understand that dereference only applies if the original type is a pointer (and makes no sense if not).

But I don't understand why this is a blocker for such an operator. Just because it doesn't apply to all types ? The compiler could just generate an error if used with something that is not a pointer type.

Comment: But I think the short answer to my question is: there is no way to declare a "dereference of a type".

Answer (score 0):

i have just an answer for you
if you want to dereference pointer with generic and there may be a type which is not a pointer but still you want the zero value of that type then this solution will be best for you

```golang
    func Deref[T any](p *T) T {
      if p != nil {
        return *p
      }
      var derefed T
      return derefed
    }
```

With this function what happens is it checks if the given type is nil or not if it's nil then it will return zero value of the type so no need to worry about underlying type as long as it's a pointer.

if you pass the non pointer variable to function it will be compilation error so no need to worry about panic.

You can try code on [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2KWPf3W760I)

Comment: hey Smit, thanks for trying. But that one is easy. My issue is that if T is a C (using CGO) forward declared type (something like `class MyClass;`), this won't compile in Go > 1.20 (it used to compile in Go 1.19). It complaints that T is not fully defined. I know it shouldn't matter, since we are only using *T, but the compiler doesn't solve for that -- I asked in Go nuts and they answered that the complexity is not worth it. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation i haven't used CGO yet so i don't know if i can answer your question. but i you were to give more explanation then i may spare some time to figure out something.

Comment: Btw, longer discussion here: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/y9IvZgiNowk/m/Vj1OzCigBgAJ