# Go function to create either new pointer or new value of a generic type

Tags: go, pointers, generics

I have a function which takes a generic type and should return a function that always return a pointer. I.e. if you pass it a non-pointer type it should return a pointer to that type, if you pass it a pointer type it should return the same type. I don't want to use `reflect.New` as it's a performance-critical app.

I don't mind using reflection in the function that returns the factory function, however ideally not even there.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Ptr[T any] interface {
    *T
}

func makeNewA[T Ptr[U], U any]() any {
    return new(U)
}

func makeNewB[T any]() any {
    return new(T)
}

func makeNew[T any](v T) func() any {
    if reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        return makeNewA[T] // <-- error: T does not match *U
    } else {
        return makeNewB[T]
    }
}

type Foo struct{}

func main() {
    make1 := makeNew(Foo{})
    make2 := makeNew(&Foo{})

    // should both return &Foo{}
    fmt.Println(make1())
    fmt.Println(make2())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of conditional typing isn't nicely solved with generics, because when you instantiate `T any` with `*Foo` you lose information about the base type. As matter of fact your code still uses reflection and `any` (= `interface{}`), and the return type of the `makeN` functions will have to be type-asserted to `*Foo`.

The closest you can get with your current code is:

```
func makeNew[T any](v T) func() any {
    if typ := reflect.TypeOf(v); typ.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        elem := typ.Elem()
        return func() any {
            return reflect.New(elem).Interface() // must use reflect
        }
    } else {
        return func() any { return new(T) } // v is not ptr, alloc with new
    }
}
```

Then both maker functions will return an `any` that wraps a non-nil `*Foo` value:

```
fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", make1(), make1()) // *main.Foo, &{}
fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", make2(), make2()) // *main.Foo, &{}
```

Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/kVUM-qVLLHG

Further considerations:

- `return makeNewA[T]` in your first attempt does not work because the condition `reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Ptr` is evaluated at runtime, whereas instantiation of `makeNewA` happens at compile-time. At compile-time `T` is simply constrained by `any` and `any` (= `interface{}`) doesn't implement `Ptr[U]`
- you can't capture information about both the pointer type and the base type with only the argument `v`. For example `makeNew[T Ptr[U], U any](v T)` won't compile when called with `makeNew(Foo{})` and `makeNew[T Ptr[U], U any](v U)` will infer `T` as `**Foo` when called with `*Foo`

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to create a new variable every time the resulting function is called, not just returning the original one. So is using `reflect.New` the only way?

Comment: @AdamB I changed the answer to show returning new values, although I'm afraid that yes, you've gotta use `reflect.New` for the pointer type. When `T any` matches `*Foo` you lose information about the base type. In the function body you only have `T`, and you can't "dereference" a type. Funnily, this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830472/what-is-the-dereference-operator-of-a-type-in-go-generics)

Comment: However consider benchmarking your code. I have seen that simple reflection calls  don't degrade performance that much. It may be a different story with `New` though. Otherwise, you may split `makeNew` in two functions `makeNewPtr` and `makeNewVal`, or have users supply `func[T any]() T` directly and get rid of the maker funcs

Comment: The thing is that it's a library which doesn't know if the value will be a pointer or not in advance. I've benchmarked it using `reflect.New`and it adds about 90ns/op, which in the context of processing thousands of records per second really isn't great. I might actually do a proposal for typescript style typeguards so the compiler knows what the type is.